# Scala check if string contains no special chars

Tags: regex, scala

I have written the following code to check whether a string contains special chars or not. The code looks too complicated to me but I have no idea how to make it simpler. Any Ideas?

```
def containsNoSpecialChars(string: String): Boolean = {
  val pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$".r
  return pattern.findAllIn(string).mkString.length == string.length
}                                                 //> containsNoSpecialChars: (string: String)Boolean

containsNoSpecialChars("bl!a ")                   //> res0: Boolean = false
containsNoSpecialChars("bla9")                    //> res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: BTW, I find it difficult to work with predicates that tell if something **not** holds. IMHO better would be to reverse the logic and name the thing containsSpecialChars or leave the logic at is and name it containsOnlyValidChars

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
scala> val ordinary=(('a' to 'z') ++ ('A' to 'Z') ++ ('0' to '9')).toSet
ordinary: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char] = Set(E, e, X, s, x, 8, 4, n, 9, N, j, y, T, Y, t, J, u, U, f, F, A, a, 5, m, M, I, i, v, G, 6, 1, V, q, Q, L, b, g, B, l, P, p, 0, 2, C, H, c, W, h, 7, r, K, w, R, 3, k, O, D, Z, o, z, S, d)

scala> def isOrdinary(s:String)=s.forall(ordinary.contains(_))
isOrdinary: (s: String)Boolean


scala> isOrdinary("abc")
res4: Boolean = true

scala> isOrdinary("abc!")
res5: Boolean = false
```

I used a Set, the correct choice logically, but it should also work with a Vector which will avoid you looking at the jumbled letters...

Answer (score 18):

This uses the Java string:

```
word.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
```

or if you do not want to deal with Regex one can benefit from Scala's RichString by using either:

```
word.forall(_.isLetterOrDigit)
```

or:

```
!word.exists(!_.isLetterOrDigit)
```

Comment: Is there any disadvantage when I use java string instead of scala string?

Comment: This is equivalent to Pattern.matches(regex, str) according to this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html. They are the same since Scala RichString falls to Java classes for regex operations.

Comment: There is a (small) disadvantage to this approach, but your code suffers from it as well: the pattern is compiled every single time you want to check a string. A slightly more optimal solution is to compile the pattern and store it as a class or object field.

Comment: Thank you for that advice. I will put it in a util class. Anyways the approach of this answer does not work because it only checks whether the string contains alphanumeric characters while I want to check if it does contain special chars.

Comment: That has not anything to do with Scala or Java but with Regex. Use .*\W+.* for matching strings containing non alphanumeric chars

Answer (score 7):

```
def containsNoSpecialChars(string: String) = string.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
```